# Если я проверяю доступность SD карты , стоит ли проверять разрешение?

Tags: android

// проверяем доступность SD

```
   if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SD-карта не доступна ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
```

Если на SD нет permissions в манифесте, то этот метод может вернуть положительный ответ? Или этот метод проверяет только есть ли вообще в устройстве флешка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно не только проверять есть ли разрешение, но и спрашивать у пользователя разрешение в рантайме на случай если он его отозвал (начиная с андроид 6 разрешение можно отозвать в настройках). Конечно, если вы собираетесь делать что-то с этой картой в дальшейшем.

Делается это примерно так

```
//Проверка версии SDK устройства
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                //динамическое получение прав на WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is granted");

                    //делаете что-то

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                    //запрашиваем разрешение
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
            } else {
                //делаете что-то;
            }
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=ru#WriteExternalStorage)

> Для записи во внешнее хранилище следует указать запрос разрешения
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE в файле манифеста:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

> Внимание! В настоящее время все приложения могут считывать данные из
>   внешних хранилищ без специального разрешения.
>   Однако в новой версии эта ситуация будет изменена. Если вашему
>   приложению потребуется считать данные из внешнего хранилища (но не
>   записать туда данные), вам необходимо будет декларировать разрешение
>   READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Чтобы обеспечить дальнейшую работу вашего
>   приложения ожидаемым образом, вы должны сразу декларировать это
>   разрешение до того, как изменения вступят в силу.

```
<manifest ...>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ... </manifest>
```

> Однако если ваше приложение использует разрешение
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, оно косвенно получает разрешение на чтение
>   данных из внешнего хранилища.
>
> Для сохранения файлов во внутреннем
>   хранилище не требуется никаких разрешений. У вашего приложения всегда
>   будет разрешение на чтение и запись файлов в его каталог внутренней
>   памяти

getExternalStorageState() возвращает состояние внешнего хранилища. Если возвращаемое состояние равнозначно `MEDIA_MOUNTED`, можно выполнять с файлами операции чтения и записи. (В будущем при наличии разрешения в Манифесте)

Comment: Кажется мой вопрос вы не совсем поняли.  Да, возвращаемое  состояние  равнозначно MEDIA_MOUNTED. Это означает, что в манифесте есть разрешение? Или я должен проверить и наличие в манифесте разрешения и доступность SD. Может ли быть такое что Environment.getExternalStorageState()  возращает MEDIA_MOUNTED , а разрешения в манифесте нет ?

Comment: @Turalllb: По моему наличие внешнего хранилища (состояние) и разрешение на чтение/запись не связаны между собой. Можно иметь разрешение и не иметь внешнего хранилища, можно иметь второе, но не иметь первого, а можно иметь/не иметь и первое и второе.

Comment: Ну значит ответ на мой вопрос должен быть таким: Наличие ответа MEDIA_MOUNTED, не значит что разрешение есть в манифесте. И правильно будет прописать еще и проверку на разрешение. Если скажут: Зачем проверка на разрешение, если манифест вы сами и пишете. Ответ: мою библиотеку может кто то подключить и у него в манифесте разрешения не будет. Это надо проверять.

Comment: Поправьте вывод из вашего ответа, чтобы я мог принять как правильный. Если конечно вы уверены что проверка состояния флешки никак не проверяет состояние разрешений

Comment: По поводу библиотеки хорошо бы добавить в вопрос. Нужно ли в своей библиотеке, на случай, если ее кто-то установит, проверять наличие разрешений. Но опять же, вы в своей библиотеке проверяете состояние хранилища, верно? запись/чтение то будет осуществлять непосредственно приложение в котором ваша библиотека. Этому приложению в любом случае нужны разрешения, проверяете вы их наличие или нет.

Comment: А если у меня библиотека, которая получает доступ к определенному каталогу? В данном случае так и есть. Эта библиотека может читать каталоги на флешке, а значит библиотеке нужно разрешение и она должна проверить, предоставлены ли они в манифесте. Т.е. не только приложение может что то записывать или читать, но и библиотека. Так что есть нужна проверка.

Comment: И еще. Если апи >= 23 или >23 (точно не знаю) непосредственно в onResume стоит надо проверять наличие разрешений, иначе даже имя разрешение в манифесте, можно не получить доступ. Кажется  я правильно понял это новшество . Вот материал http://ohandroid.com/is-listfiles-x.html

Comment: О, вот кстати новый ответ и он правильный, там написано то о чем я говорю. ТЕперь нужно обязательно проверять есть ли разрешение. Новые апи новые правила...

Comment: @Turallib. Изучу вопрос более детально.  Ответ удалю

Comment: Не удаляйте ответ, под ним наши комментарии, которые могут быть кому то полезны.